# Bootstrap 4 minimum page/sidebar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav>...</nav> <!-- sidebar -->
        <main role="main">
            <!-- content -->
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set a minimum height because when content is too short, the sidebar looks like this:

[image]

*Notice the empty white bottom of the image*

Setting `html, body, .container-fluid, .row` height to 100% fixes this on this page, but breaks pages with content longer than 100% (the sidebar is again too short, but this time it's (only) 100% of the screen height):

[image]

*That is the sidebar after I scroll, it doesn't go beyond 100%.*

I want the sidebar to have 1OO% height when content is shorter than the screen, and to be as high as the content when the content is longer than the screen. **How do I set a minimum height for the sidebar (or the .container-fluid)?** `nav { min-height: 100%; }` didn't work either. It seems like min-height works very strangely in CSS3.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uc9gm2ke/3/

Comment: Is the position of the sidebar is fixed?

Comment: Can you share a live code example? _(codepen or jsfiddle)_

Comment: @YashuMittal Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/uc9gm2ke/3/

Comment: I had the same issue before i solve it setting the right col height:100vh, then inside of it i put a scrollable div or maybe in your case you can set the ul scrollable, so it doesn&#39;t affects the side bar when scrolling, and you also can set your nav in this case with height:100vh

Comment: It is showing this https://i.imgur.com/Nol52Xl.png

Comment: Yes, the sidebar's height is too small. It should look like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/v4gMjhVW5b/bootstrap-4-full-height-column (note that this is the solution that breaks pages where content is longer than 100%)

Comment: This is the solution I already mentioned. It breaks pages where content is longer than 100%. https://imgur.com/a/by9fqL3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by copying code from this codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/kTmpqn61nq

CSS:

```
body, html, .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100%;
}

main {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML:

- Add `wrapper` class to the main `.row` div.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/uc9gm2ke/16/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra CSS to add, this HTML works perfectly.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2   navbar navbar-expand-md   navbar-dark bg-dark   pt-md-3 pl-md-2 pl-xl-3   d-md-block"> <!-- d-flex -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Administration
        </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" aria-controls="sidebar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse mt-md-1" id="sidebar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-block mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item w-100 btn btn-dark text-left">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item w-100 btn btn-dark text-left">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                Orders
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 px-4">
          some content
          <!-- when you uncomment code below, it works -->
           <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>a
          lot of content
        </main>

      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with screen width. Same issue: https://imgur.com/a/by9fqL3

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to make the `position` of the sidebar fixed.

Comment: But when the content's height is over 100%, `height: 100vh` makes the sidebar too short.

Comment: How's that possible, I have tried that in jsfiddle and it worked perfectly earlier.

Comment: If you are comfortable, can you share your local server with me so that I can debug it from my end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180626/discussion-between-yashu-mittal-and-samuel-shifterovich).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52469333/2 Obviously, the comment says `<!-- when you uncomment code below, it works -->`. When you comment it, it doesn't work.